# ClosedXml C# to display formula output numbers

Tags: c#, closedxml

I'm using closedxml to generate and download an xlsx file from a .NET c# application

Is there a way to display the formulas output numbers without the user having to click Enable Editing after downloading and opening the file in excel?

Comment: You can't change that while generating the files. You have to disable Proteced View for files from the Internet in Excel itself, but that can be unsecure. See [here](https://www.cnet.com/how-to/how-to-disable-protected-view-in-microsoft-word/) and [here](https://blogs.technet.microsoft.com/office2010/2009/08/13/protected-view-in-office-2010/) for more information.

Comment: Thank you, but is it possible to display just the output of the formulas without disabling protected view

Comment: No, the only thing you could do is to calculate the results and put them also in the file (in a seperate column for example).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

There is an overload which allows you to evaluate formulas when saving the file. It's disabled by default.

```
void Save(Boolean validate, Boolean evaluateFormulae = false);

void SaveAs(String file, Boolean validate, Boolean evaluateFormulae = false);
```

Comment: Thank you it works i get the output of the formulas, but I lose the alignment and number formatting modifications I made on those cells.

Comment: That could be a separate, independent bug.